# C++ Linked List causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My code is below, and my problem occurs when I am trying to "loadFile" through my program.  It asks me for the filename, and when I give it a filename that it can find, it just says "Segmentation Fault" and stops running.  I think the problem is either coming from the loadFile method itself or on line 244 which is where I'm writing the method for adding an element to the linkedlist.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

http://pastebin.com/7qZY9Hef

Line 224:

```
 void countyElectionList::push_back(countyElectionResults * newCER){

    if(head == NULL)
head = newCER;
else
    {
    countyElectionResults * current = head;
    while(current->getNextResult() != NULL){
        current = current->getNextResult();
    }
current->setNextResult(newCER);
}

    }
```

Comment: Post more relative code here, its still not clear

Comment: What else should I post?  The original code was way too long so I felt I should only post what was relevant to the error?

Comment: Do you have some really good reason for not using the stl containers?

Comment: 1) this won't compile. 2) *YOU* think that's the relevant part. What if you're wrong?

Comment: As printed the code won't compile. Pay attention to your braces.

Comment: Is `newCER -> nextResult` set to `NULL`?

Comment: Is it just me or is there a syntax error here? Isnt there a missing `}` after `head = newCER`?

Comment: I am missing a bracket, which I will take care of right now in an edit.  If that is not the relevant part, Karoly Horvath, then I have pasted the pastebin for the entire project.  Thanks for the input guys keep it coming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code at the URL you linked (which *also* will not compile for a number of reasons, including missing brackets and functions missing return statements, among other things) the problem is here:

```
// A constructor that initializes the private data members
countyElectionList::countyElectionList(){

}
```

You never initialize `countyElectionList::head` to NULL, so when you call `countyElectionList::push_back` the value of `head` will most likely *not* point to NULL but to who-knows-what... hence the crash.

For future reference: when you debug crashes if the function in which the crash occurs doesn't look suspicious and you can't find a fault with the source code and in stepping through the logic step-by-step, you should move on to examining the caller(s) of the function.

Update: So, after examining your new pastebin code (which *still* does not compile, as several functions which claim to return values lack return statements) the error continues to be in the same function:

```
// A constructor that initializes the private data members
countyElectionList::countyElectionList(){
    countyElectionList::head == NULL;
}
```

Notice that you using `==` which is the *comparison* operator and **not** the assignment operator, which is `=`. This is the correct code to use:

```
// A constructor that initializes the private data members
countyElectionList::countyElectionList(){
    head = NULL;
}
```

I have to wonder if you actually even tried to compile this code. I did, and my compiler immediately pointed the error out to me. It even told me what to do:

> test.cpp(210) : warning C4553: '==' : operator has no effect; did you
>   intend '='?

I also suspect that you are in way over your head. I am assuming that this is homework and you're not doing an actual election system (*although...*) so I guess my next question is: have you considered talking to your professor and explaining how you having difficulty with the syntax of the language? Perhaps your school has resources that could help. Trying to program by randomly inserting stuff in a file doesn't help you learn; it's an exercise in frustration.

Comment: I do initialize it in my new version, and i'm Still getting a segmentation fault.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code that you have on your pastebin link won't compile and I really don't have the time to get it to compile. I suspect that you have similar issues elsewhere. Please make sure variables are appropriately initialized before they are used.

Comment: Would you be willing to give it one last look if I upload a version that DOES compile to pastebin?  Thanks Nik.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm so stupid.  Yes I am in a little a bit over my head as we seemed to have jumped from pointers to this code and I'm confused out of my mind as to what's going on.  I'll try to get some extra help with the prof tomorrow.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of stupidity. It's simply an issue of being in a class that has some prerequisites you don't have. Ask for help from your Professor, and help yourself by picking up a good introductory book to C++.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with, it looks like you never initialize `head` to `NULL` in  the constructor for `countyElectionList`.

That could cause problems when you later try to use `head`, e.g. in `countyElectionList::push_back`.

Comment: How would I do that?  Are you sure?

Comment: Tried that, still gives a segmentation fault =(